# assert and verify in Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests

Can someone explain what the difference between assert and verify is please.

I know that verify means it checks if it is there, if it isn't the test fails and stops there (correct?).

So does assert carry on even if it does fail?

I've read the documentation and still can't get my head round it.

Comment: [this link might help](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2012/11/different-between-verifytext-and.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you've got it backwards. In Selenium IDE, both `verifyWhatever` and `assertWhatever` commands determine if the specified condition is true, and then different things happen.  The `assertWhatever` command fails the test immediately if the condition is false.  The `verifywhatever` command allows the test to continue, but will cause it to fail when it ends.  Thus, if your test requires you to check for the presence of several items, none of which are present, `assertElementPresent` will fail on the first, while `verifyElementPresent` will fail reporting that all are missing.

The down side to `verifyWhatever` is that you really can't trust the behavior of any test after one of its verifications fails.  Since the application isn't responding correctly, you have no way of knowing whether subsequent assertion or verification failures are valid or are the result of the earlier failures.  Thus some of us think `verifyWhatever` commands are Evil.

Comment: Note that this is true for e.g. `verifyElementPresent` but not true for `verifyText`. If the latter is false, selenium fails the test immediately.