# What is the different between Assert ElementPresent and Verify ElementPresent

Tags: selenium

what is the different between selenium - Assert/Verify ElementPresent.
How to execute different browser using selenium IDE
What are the command used for ajax in selenium IDE

Thanx in advanced

Answer (score 2):

"All Selenium Assertions can be used in 3 modes: "assert", "verify", and "waitFor". For example, you can "assertText", "verifyText" and "waitForText". When an "assert" fails, the test is aborted. When a "verify" fails, the test will continue execution, logging the failure. This allows a single "assert" to ensure that the application is on the correct page, followed by a bunch of "verify" assertions to test form field values, labels, etc."  http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html

Also, on this site, [assert vs. verify in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743848/assert-vs-verify-in-selenium) and [assert and verify in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978011/assert-and-verify-in-selenium)

This required less than five minutes of searching on Google.  (I typed in `verify element present`, Google autocompleted `in selenium`, and it was the first link on the page.)  The two on-site links were done as a side thought and took even less time.  I would suggest that you go back and search more thoroughly for the answers to the other two parts of your question, as I suspect they will be just as easy to find - and it would cost less of both your time and ours.

Comment: Thanx.Do you have any idea about the  How to execute different browser using selenium IDE What are the command used for ajax in selenium IDE

Comment: I would suggest that you go back and search more thoroughly for the answers to the other two parts of your question, as I suspect they will be just as easy to find - and it would cost less of both your time and ours.

Comment: sorry for the troublling